# How to move images in a circular motion without rotating the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a webpage using html5, css3 and javascript...In my webpage a video is played in the center of the page around which 5 images will move around the video in circular way, without the image is rotated...how can i achieve this??  i'm a beginner...pls help me out...thnx in advance

Answer (score 3):

Just calculate the image coordinates using basic trigonometry:

```
              y
              |
              |     [image]
              |    /
              |   /
              |  / radius
              | /
    __________|/_)_image_angle___________ x
              |
              |
              |
```

Basic trigonometry gives us:

```
cos(image_angle) = x/radius
sin(image_angle) = y/radius
```

therefore

```
x = cos(image_angle) / radius
y = sin(image_angle) / radius
```

So simply animate the images by changing their CSS coordinates. So for one image it should be something like:

```
var img = document.getElementById('image1');
var radius = 200; // in pixels
var imgAngle = 0;

function animateImg () {
    img.style.left = cos(imgAngle)/radius;
    img.style.top = sin(imgAngle)/radius;

    imgAngle = imgAngle + 0.1;

    setTimeout(animateImg,50);
}

animateImg();
```

For five images just offset each image by 2*PI/5:

```
function animageImages () {
    // Assuming image elements are stored in an array, I'm
    // using the array length to infer the number of images:

    var offsetAngle = 2 * Math.PI / images.length;

    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
        var img = images[i];
        img.style.left = cos(imgAngle+offsetAngle*i)/radius;
        img.style.top = sin(imgAngle+offsetAngle*i)/radius;
    }

    imgAngle = imgAngle + 0.1;

    setTimeout(animateImages,50);
}
```

Of course, the examples above all animate around the top left corner of the page (coordinate 0,0). You need to recenter the calculations around the coordinates of your video. Also, if you're not familiar with CSS, you need to set the style for the images to `display:block` and `position:absolute` (or relative) for this to work.